# Unable to cqlsh to a cassandra docker container remotely

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db_cassandra:
    container_name: db_cassandra
    image: custom.cassandra.image/builder-cassandra
    volumes:
      - "./common/cassandra:/lua/cassandra_setup:rw"
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u", "cassandra", "-p", "cassandra" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  remote_cassandra:
    container_name: remote_cassandra
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./it/remote_cassandra/Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: custom.cassandra.image/builder-cassandra
    depends_on:
      dd_cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - "./common/cassandra:/lua/cassandra_setup:rw"
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
```

Here's the `remote_cassandra/Dockerfile`:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

COPY ./it/common/cassandra/cassandra-setup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /cassandra-setup.sh

CMD ["/cassandra-setup.sh"]
```

`remote_cassandra` remotely connects to the `db_cassandra` service and executes certain queries.

Here's how the `cassandra-setup.sh` script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#code that creates schema.cql
.
.
.
while ! cqlsh db_cassandra -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "waiting for db_cassandra to be up..."
  sleep .5
done
cqlsh db_cassandra -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
```

The while loop makes `remote_cassandra` wait until the db_cassandra is up and running so that it can then run the schema.cql remotely to populate certain tables present in db_cassandra.

However, the above script runs into an infinite loop where `remote_cassandra` is unable to remotely `cqlsh` to `db_cassandra`.

Here are the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2357, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2303, in main
    shell = Shell(hostname,
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 463, in __init__
    load_balancing_policy=WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy([self.hostname]),
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/policies.py", line 425, in __init__
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/policies.py", line 426, in <listcomp>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
waiting for db_cassandra to be up...
```

The above logs keeps getting printed again and again.

What can be done here to form a connection?

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to pass the name of db_cassandra as cli arg to bash script - cassandra-setup.sh. However, when running docker-compose, it takes forever for the container to run.

Here's how I'm passing the arg:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/cassandra-setup.sh"]
CMD ["db_cassandra"]
```

and then cqlsh(ing) it like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_CONTAINER="$1"
#code that creates schema.cql
.
.
.
while ! cqlsh $DB_CONTAINER -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "waiting for db_cassandra to be up..."
  sleep .5
done
cqlsh $DB_CONTAINER -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
```

This somehow just creates both the cassandra and the execution seems to be stuck forever like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the `custom.cassandra.image/builder-cassandra` image so just using `cassandra:latest` in the `db_cassandra` service.

Here's a minimal setup that does what you require.

```
├── cassandra-setup.sh
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile
```

`docker-compose.yml` (Based on the `docker-compose.yml` but stripped down to minimal requirements.)

```
version: "3"
services:
  db_cassandra:
    container_name: db_cassandra
    image: cassandra:latest
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u", "cassandra", "-p", "cassandra" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    logging:
      driver: none

  remote_cassandra:
    container_name: remote_cassandra
    build:
      context: .
```

`Dockerfile` (I'm not sure what you are specifying for `BASE_IMAGE` so I used `cassandra:latest`.)

```
FROM cassandra:latest

COPY cassandra-setup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /cassandra-setup.sh

CMD ["/cassandra-setup.sh"]
```

`cassandra-setup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " Starting setup."

until cqlsh -e "describe cluster" db_cassandra 9042 >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  echo " Waiting for Cassandra to be ready."
  sleep 10
done

echo " Cassandra is ready. Describe the keyspaces."
cqlsh -e "describe keyspaces" db_cassandra 9042

echo " Done!"
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you're redirecting output to /dev/null? Any reason?

Comment: That's just to keep the logs clean so you can clearly see the "waiting for..." messages. It has no functional purpose. Feel free to remove.

Comment: I guess you only added port number in the cqlsh command apart from what I currently have. This didn't work form me though.

Comment: Did you try the precise setup I provided? Can you please elaborate on what "didn't work form me though"? What part of this did not work for you?

Comment: Trying to help, but if you don't provide more information then this is a dead end for me.

Comment: Thanks, it works, Just one thing - Added in the edits.